# REGEX para Seleciar uma linha que contem um string desenjada

Tags: python

Gostaria de selecionar uma linha inteira que contenha uma string desejada.
Por exemplo:

String: "LED AZUL deve acender"

texto:

Ao apertar o botão o LED AZUL deve acender por 5 segundos de acordo com as caracteristicas do teste.

Gostaria de selecionar toda a linha que contenha a string "LED AZUL deve acender" através de uma Regex que possa usar em notepad++ ou python. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado!!

Comment: No caso do Notepad++, se você quer encontrar uma *linha inteira* (isto é, fazer o *matching* na linha toda) se ela contiver a string `LED AZUL`, basta usar a expressão regular: `^.*LED AZUL.*$`. O `^` indica o começo da linha e o `$` indica o fim da linha. O `.*` indica qualquer caractere, em qualquer quantidade (entre o começo da linha e o LED AZUL, e depois entre o LED AZUL e o final da linha).

Comment: Obrigado @LuizVieira !!

Comment: Utilizando o gedit do ubuntu, eu consegui utilizar a seguinte sintaxe: ^.*Frase para ser localizada.+ Caso não utilize o ".+" no final, ele pega só até a frase desejada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com python é relativamente facil, nem precisas usar regex:

```
str_desejada = 'LED AZUL deve acender'
for linha in linhas:
    if str_desejada in linha:
        print('existe')
```

Com regex:

```
import re

linha = 'Ao apertar o botão o LED AZUL deve acender por 5 segundos de acordo com as caracteristicas do teste.'
comp = re.compile('LED AZUL deve acender')
for linha in linhas:
    match = comp.search(linha)
    if match:
        print('existe')
```

Comment: Valeu Miguel obrigado pela ajuda! Poderia me ajudar com a regex para encontrar este caso ae? Obrigado!!

Comment: @DiegoSanchesGarcia coloquei em cima, mas para este caso específico, sem mais informação, eu optaria pela primeira solução

Comment: Obrigado Miguel!!

Comment: De nada @DiegoSanchesGarcia, ainda bem que ajudei